# Image resize after download in android

Tags: android

[image]I am downloading image from server in AsyncTask method. It shows the image in full screen while it is downloading but when the download is completed the image became small in center of the screen.

Here is the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.show_pics);

    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

    downloadTask.execute("https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/21/posts/19431/featured_image/CodeFeature.jpg");
}

private Bitmap downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream iStream = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);
        /** Creating an http connection to communcate with url */
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        /** Connecting to url */
        urlConnection.connect();

        /** Reading data from url */
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        /** Creating a bitmap from the stream returned from the url */
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
    }
    return bitmap;
}

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... url) {
        try {
            bitmap = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        /** Getting a reference to ImageView to display the
         * downloaded image
         */
        ImageView iView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.TahlilImageView);

        /** Displaying the downloaded image */
        iView.setImageBitmap(result);

        /** Showing a message, on completion of download process */
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Image downloaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your xml code

Comment: When the image is downloading you don't have the image yet, so how is it possible to show it full screen. Are you sure you have not set the same image as the background for the imageview statically in xml or java code.

Comment: yes that was my mistake. i had set it. i removed it and while downloading nothing is shown and when download is completed the image is shown in center and it is not in full screen them @Tony

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at the following URL regarding the [ImageView.ScaleType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

The ScaleType is giving you options for scaling the bounds of an image to the bounds of the ImageView. You can either set it throught the XML by declaring the following attribute:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Or you can set it dynamically in your code:

```
iView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

If you want the Image to **fill** the whole space of the ImageView you have to select the FIT_XY. In general you have many option, and you can expirement with them. And as a result, to select the one that fits your need the best.